# Getting the React CORS preflight error in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cors

I am getting the CORS access error in my React Native app when connecting to an external API.

```
async componentDidMount() {
// POST request using fetch with async/await
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ type:'accountLookup',storeId:STORE_ID, storeKey:STORE_KEY, memberId:'471324' })
};
const response = await fetch('http://frequent5.revlogical.com/wsMobile', requestOptions);
const data = await response.json();
this.setState({ data: data });
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is most likely not with React app, rather with your server which is not configurated to serve your app.
You should set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header on your server to allow your app's address to make requests.

Answer (score -1):

This problem is usually the fault of the backend. Test it with a tool like https://www.test-cors.org/

An alternative is to create a server to be intercepted between the frontend and the API, and you can handle this guy's cors

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).